# typescript maximum depth inferred types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm running into a weird issue where typescricpt is failing to properly infer the type when using nested 'keyof'

I was able to get it to work up to a depth of 2 (need to go to 3) in my actual code but in the example below I was only even able to get a depth of 1.

```
type Base = {
    a: A;
};

type A = {
    b: B;
};

type B = {
    c: C;
};

type C = {
    d: string;
};

type DrillDown1<KBase extends keyof Base> = Base[KBase]['b']; // fine

type DrillDown2<KBase extends keyof Base, KA extends keyof Base[KBase]> = Base[KBase][KA]; // fine
type DrillDown2a = DrillDown2<'a', 'b'>['c']; // fine

type DrillDown3<KBase extends keyof Base, KA extends keyof Base[KBase]> = Base[KBase][KA]['c']; // Type '"c"' cannot be used to index type 'Base[KBase][KA]'.ts(2536)
```

Any ideas how to get around this issue?